# Populate a Div with the content from a select list

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate a Div with the selection from a select list. I can get it to work but the result is the value and I want the selected words.

Whatever the selection is the words appear in the Div:

```
<div id="Requests">Requests</div>
<div id="Requests">Issues</div>
<div id="Requests">Incidents</div>
```

This is what I am working with;

My select list

```
<select name="ReportCat" id="ReportCat" class="imaindatesel" >
<option value="0">Select...</option>
<option value="1">Requests</option>
<option value="2">Issues</option>
<option value="3">Incidents</option>
</select>
```

My Div

```
<div id="Requests"></div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#ReportCat').change(function(){

        $('#Requests').html($('#ReportCat').val());        
    });
});
```

Can anyone please help, many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use : `$("#ReportCat :selected").text()` to get the text of selected option.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#ReportCat').change(function(){

      $('#Requests').html($("#ReportCat :selected").text());          
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ReportCat" id="ReportCat" class="imaindatesel" >
<option value="0">Select...</option>
<option value="1">Requests</option>
<option value="2">Issues</option>
<option value="3">Incidents</option>
</select>

<div id="Requests"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the text, use `$('#ReportCat').text()` instead of `$('#ReportCat').val()`.

```
$(function(){
    $('#ReportCat').change(function(){
        $('#Requests').html($('#ReportCat:selected').text());        
    });
});
```

Also, you have repeated ID's for your div's. An ID is unique so I would suggest changing that to a class.